# Porting a Qt Application from Linux to Windows

Tags: qt, opengl, qt4

I built a qt application that uses opengl on linux and am trying to build it on windows. I used g++ to make it on linux and am using command line nmake for Visual Studio 2005 to build it on windows. When I tryed to build my application I typed

```
qmake -makefile app.pro
nmake
```

The nmake failed and said "bool qt_win_owndc_required"... already defined in QtOpenGld.lib ..
one or more multiply definded symbols found

When I tried building one of the examples (hellogl) with opengl it resulted in the same error message. But when I tried building a different example without opengl it worked fine. Do I need to do something special to build the opengl library correctly? Is there something that I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running qmake in a Visual Studio 2005 Command prompt?

A google search turned up this post: http://www.delta3d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?showtopic=15723

The guy fixed the problem by rebuilding the source.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Rebuilding it worked. I have no idea what went wrong the first time but since rebuilding worked I'm not going to worry about it.